# how to implement reload app in react native expo (production)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, reload

I tried to create restart with react-native-restart, but I get an error when calling RNRestart.Restart():

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeRestart.default.Restart')]

How do I implement reload in production ?

p.s. I use expo

Comment: i already was reading

Comment: if you are using a managed workflow, call `reloadAsync` from expo-updates

Answer (score 13):

you can use [expo-updates](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/updates/) just run `expo install expo-updates` and restart the app with the method reloadAsync

```
import * as Updates from 'expo-updates';
Updates.reloadAsync()
```